# C# dynamic control names in .NET CF

Tags: c#, dynamic, controls, accessibility

I'm working with .NET CF framework in c#, and I want to know if I can access the controls somehow like this:

```
string field="txtName";
this.Controls[field];
```

or is this impossibile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using Linq?

```
var myControl = this.Controls.Cast<Control>().OfType<WhateverControlType>().FirstOrDefault(cont => cont.ID == "myControlId");
```

Something like that?

Comment: I used this:

var myControl = this.Controls.Cast<Control>().OfType<TransparentLabel>().FirstOrDefault(cont => cont.Name = myStr);

the result:

Error 4 Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<SmartDeviceProject1.TransparentLabel,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type D:\JOB\VS C#\CONTIPLAY\V2\SmartDeviceProject1\Forms\frmMachines.cs 185 109 SmartDeviceProject1

Comment: well I didn't try it in VS, but I think something -like- that should work.

Comment: I see: you should use '==' not '='

Comment: If that works, you can make it an extension method 'FindControl' on ControlCollection

Answer (score 2):

I think the method you're after is `FindControl` - you'll find that method on anything with a `Controls` collection.

Comment: this would be perfect, but in Compact framework I don't have this method

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it would be wrong, the indexer expects a `string`, and you're passing a `string`, so for me it's correct.

Comment: a control collection takes an int, you'd need FindControl

Comment: this.Controls expects integer indexes. I want to know if I can acces the controls by name.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was too quick...  As other said, you'll need to use `FindControl` method. (I should have written "If the indexer expects..." :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to reference a control in the control collection by name (stirng) or index (int).  The only thing you will need to do additionally is cast the control into the type of object it is.  Something like the following.

MyControl c (MyControl)this.Controls["ControlName"];

Enjoy!

Comment: this isn't good either because the indexer expects integer values